# Riemann-Roch theorem for arbitrary 1-dim schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Please I am looking for a reference on Riemann-Roch theorem for 1-dimensional schemes (and not necessarily varieties) if there is any.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe you should precise what you want to be called Riemann-Roch in this context : for example, is it about divisors or line bundles ?
(different things on a singular curve)

Comment: Are your schemes over a field or do you want a Riemann-Roch for $Spec(\mathbb{Z})$ and its finite covers?

Comment: There is also arithmetic Rieman-Roch for prime spectrum of ring of integers of number field. Like here https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4250/h18/arithmeticrr.pdf

Answer (score 2):

You may find the paper [Generalized divisors on Gorenstein curves and a theorem of Noether](https://doi.org/10.1215/kjm/1250520873) of Hartshorne to be helpful.